# Timeout waiting for response from storage host

Tags: apache-cloudstack

We are evaluating moving from ESXi standalone hosts to Cloudstack. I've used the documentation here http://cloudstack-installation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/qig.html to do a single machine setup on a fresh instance of CentOS 6.6.

Installation is complete, however I cannot add any ISO templates. When I add any version of CentOS 6 (tried 6.5 and 6.6 minimal) I get the cryptic "Timeout waiting for response from storage host.". I tested the two NFS shares that are setup in the install and they can both be mounted with no issue.

Are there logs that might give me more information as to what is going on? From going through /var/logs/cloudstack all I'm getting are a pile tomcat and java logs with nothing obviously referencing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently their firewall configuration is just wrong (I was iffy on it originally but decided to stick with it). Stopping iptables allows the image to be uploaded, I assume restarting the services will re-add the firewall rules we DO need.